# field-of-use restrictions in Java?

Tags: java, oracle

Current field-of-use restrictions defined in "[Oracle Binary Code License Agreement for the Java SE Platform Products](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/index.html)" prohibit its use in embedded systems.

> "General Purpose Desktop Computers and Servers" means computers,
>   including desktop and laptop computers, or servers, used for general
>   computing functions under end user control (such as but not
>   specifically limited to email, general purpose Internet browsing, and
>   office suite productivity tools). The use of Software in systems and
>   solutions that provide dedicated functionality (other than as
>   mentioned above) or designed for use in embedded or function-specific
>   software applications... are excluded from this definition and not
>   licensed under this Agreement.

Do these restrictions also apply to OpenJDK and other possible implementations? Is the only way to use Java in such an environment to acquire a separate license from Oracle?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a legal question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, these restrictions do not apply to OpenJDK. They are only for the Oracle-branded binary installation packages of the JDK and JRE (which I think still include some code that is not in OpenJDK).

If you use OpenJDK, you are only bound by the OpenJDK's license, which is "GPL+linking exception".